# How do I use "as" to check if an object is of a type passed by argument?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a list of object of different types; they can be of type Lemon, Strawberry, Grape. They all inherit Fruit. They may also implement interfaces like ISour, IGrowOnTree etc.

Now, I'd like to write a method to get, from said list, all the instances that can be converted to a certain type.

What I do now is get all the elements and locally in my caller function filter them like:

```
List<Fruit> myFruits = fruitBasket.GetAllTheFruits();
List<ISour> mySourFruit = new List<ISour>();
foreach (var fruit in myFruit)
{
    var sourFruit = fruit as ISour;
    if (sourFruit != null)
        mySourFruit.Add(sourFruit);
}
```

I moved this logic inside my Basket so I don't have to rewrite the filter all the time. I was able to do this with generics, like:

```
public function List<T> GetFruits<T>() where T : class
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var fruit in this._allFruits)
    {
        var fruitAsT = fruit as T;
        if (fruitAsT != null)
            result.Add(fruitAsT);
    }
    return result;
}
```

For the sake of argument, is it possible to write this in the form:

```
public function List<Fruit> GetFruits(Type type)
```

So instead of calling:

```
var myFruits = basket.GetFruits<ISour>();
```

I'd rather call:

```
var myFruits = basket.GetFruits(typeof(ISour))
```

or something similar (so, passing the type as argument instead of using a generic)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that when generics does this beautifully? Is there a specific reason? You can also use `if (fruit is T) result.Add(fruit as T);` to avoid the unnecessary object creation.

Comment: So, so far you've re-invented [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) (but a more restricted variant). Any reason for that?

Comment: @EvilTak "for the sake of argument" :)

Comment: You can't use 'as'  for type conversion or 'is' for type check when you have  the type as a parameter. Check the method Convert.ChangeType() instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever apart of the simplest one? No particular reason. Didn't know about that.

Comment: @ccalboni you can try using `fruit.GetType()` and comparing it with `type`.

Comment: @EvilTak fruit.GetType() gives me the class of fruit, not the interface(s) it implements, am I right?

Comment: I believe if you pass in a strongly typed list as the argument (for example, an empty list to store the results in) the proper generic function would be determined by the compiler based on the argument type (specifically the list type argument). Didn't try it out though.

Comment: @ccalboni yeah, my bad.

Comment: @cdel that's actually the answer I think, thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you may not believe but I swear the fruits example is accidentally similar to MSDN's one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the generics, you have to use the various instance methods available on `Type`. [`Type.IsInstanceOfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx) is the most obvious in this case:

```
public List<Fruit> GetFruits(Type type)
{
    var result = new List<Fruit>();

    foreach (var fruit in this._allFruits)
    {
        if (type.IsInstanceOfType(fruit))
        {
            result.Add(fruit);
        }                            
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Interesting; does this leverage on reflection or do you see any particular performance issue in using this?

Comment: http://www.monitis.com/blog/2012/05/16/improving-net-application-performance-part-15-reflection-and-late-binding lists it as part of reflection. Thinking about it, it is hard to see how it could work without reflection in the general case (i.e. compile `GetFruits` without context, for example in a library). If, on the other hand, the calling site is known at compile time, the compiler could in theory see both list types and produce more efficient code. The JIT could do that, too, at run time, but it seems fairly sophisticated.

Comment: Thank you @PeterA.Schneider; I found other solutions using reflection but a bit intricated; this is much more elegant. I'll stick to the generic one but I think this pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the generics solution and pass in the result list to help the compiler determine the applicable type:

```
namespace FruitListTest
{
    class Fruit { }
    class Apple : Fruit { }

    class Program
    {
        static List<Fruit> fruitList = new List<Fruit>();

        public static void GetSpecificFruits<specificFruit>(List<specificFruit> specificFruits) 
            where specificFruit : Fruit
        {
            foreach (var fruit in fruitList)
            {
                var fruitAsT = fruit as specificFruit;
                if (fruitAsT != null)
                    specificFruits.Add(fruitAsT);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Apple> applesInFruits = new List<Apple>();
            GetSpecificFruits(applesInFruits);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution can be beautified in a number of ways: One could return the list to simplify chaining etc; one could return the number, or a boolean (any apples in there?). One could pass in two arguments (the source list, too) to have a freestanding function. One could make either one of the two arguments a `this` parameter, so that a call like `fruits.GetSpecificFruits(appleList)`  or `appleList.FillFrom(fruitList)` would be possible. If the generic fruit list is always the same, the call boils down to `appleList.Fill()` (fill it implicitly from `fruitList`) which seems elegant.

Comment: The compiler still needs to know the type at compile time, so nothing's really changed. If you can use this, surely you can use the original method? It's a matter of style, but I'd probably prefer a return value to modifying an argument.

Comment: (1) I wasn't sure just why the OP wanted a `Type`  argument instead of a generic function; one possibility was that the OP found the `basket.GetFruits<ISour>();` notation awkward. (I find that at times.) Letting the compiler choose the right template specialization by function argument looks perhaps less strange. (2) Regarding compile time/run time: Both functions can be compiled without knowing the type; on the caller side the type must be known with generics and will usually be known with the `Type` argument because it's likely to be used with a constant (as in `typeof(ISour)`).